# JAXB parses XML child into null only the Attributes are set in the object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have information as an `XML` file. To use them i want to parse the XML into objects via `JAXB`.
My only problem is that all child-notes are after the parsing `null`. Only the attributes got parsed.

root class:

```
package xml;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import xml.messstrecke.ZEBMessstrecke;

@XmlRootElement(name = "RohdatenTP2Netz", namespace = "http://www.BASt.de/ZEB/Rohdaten/Version_3_0")
public class RohdatenTP2Netz
{
    //Attributes
    private String merkmal;
    private String typ;
    private Date erstelldatum;
    private String bemerkung;

    //List of Childs
    private List<ZEBMessstrecke> zebMessstrecken;

    public @XmlAttribute(name = "Merkmal", required = true) String getMerkmal()
    {
        return merkmal;
    }
    public void setMerkmal(String merkmal)
    {
        this.merkmal = merkmal;
    }
    public @XmlAttribute(name = "Typ", required = true) String getTyp()
    {
        return typ;
    }
    public void setTyp(String typ)
    {
        this.typ = typ;
    }
    public @XmlAttribute(name = "Erstelldatum", required = true) Date getErstelldatum()
    {
        return erstelldatum;
    }
    public void setErstelldatum(Date erstelldatum)
    {
        this.erstelldatum = erstelldatum;
    }
    public @XmlAttribute(name = "Bemerkung", required = true) String getBemerkung()
    {
        return bemerkung;
    }
    public void setBemerkung(String bemerkung)
    {
        this.bemerkung = bemerkung;
    }
    public @XmlElement(required = true, type = ZEBMessstrecke.class) List<ZEBMessstrecke> getZebMessstrecken()
    {
        return zebMessstrecken;
    }
    public void setZebMessstrecken(List<ZEBMessstrecke> zebMessstrecken)
    {
        this.zebMessstrecken = zebMessstrecken;
    }
}
```

the child-class for ZEBMessstrecke:

```
package xml.messstrecke;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import xml.messstrecke.datenstrom.Datenstrom;

@XmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.BASt.de/ZEB/Rohdaten/Version_3_0")
public class ZEBMessstrecke
{
    //Attribute
    private String mnr;
    private String mra;

    //KindElemente
    private ZEBHeader header;
    private List<Datenstrom> datenstroeme;

    public @XmlAttribute(name = "mnr", required = true) String getMnr()
    {
        return mnr;
    }
    public void setMnr(String mnr)
    {
        this.mnr = mnr;
    }
    public @XmlAttribute(name = "mra", required = true) String getMra()
    {
        return mra;
    }
    public void setMra(String mra)
    {
        this.mra = mra;
    }
    public @XmlElement(name = "ZEBHeader", required = true) ZEBHeader getHeader()
    {
        return header;
    }
    public void setHeader(ZEBHeader header)
    {
        this.header = header;
    }
    public @XmlElement(name = "Datenstrom", required = true) List<Datenstrom> getDatenstroeme()
    {
        return datenstroeme;
    }
    public void setDatenstroeme(List<Datenstrom> datenstroeme)
    {
        this.datenstroeme = datenstroeme;
    }
}
```

the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<RohdatenTP2Netz Merkmal="Griffigkeit" Typ="Netzorientiert" Erstelldatum="2012-09-28" xmlns="http://www.BASt.de/ZEB/Rohdaten/Version_3_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Bemerkung="">
    <ZEBMessstrecke mnr="357/11" mra="0.4">
        <ZEBHeader>
            <Bildparameter Datentraeger="LISt__BSt_12_001">
                <Messpunktabstand_Bilder>1 Wert pro 10 Meter</Messpunktabstand_Bilder>
                <Kamera Nr="1" Name="Frontkamera" PixelH="720" PixelV="576" Bildformat="jpg" RootVerzeichnis="Kamera_01\B 096_"/>
            </Bildparameter>
            <Zusatzparameter/>
            <MapInfoStrassennetz Pfad_und_Basisname="ZEB2012B_1400_GRUNDDATEN_V_1_0_0">
                <DAT>X</DAT>
                <ID>X</ID>
                <MAP>X</MAP>
                <TAB>X</TAB>
            </MapInfoStrassennetz>
            <ZEBAdministration Jahr="2012" Strassenklasse="B" ZENDI="140000" Anlass="Zwischentermin2" Dateiversion="1"/>
            <Messparameter Messsystem="SKM" KfzKennz="MW-LI 21" Messgeraetebauer="BfW Traunstein" Messsystembetreiber="LISt GmbH Rochlitz" Messprinzip="schraeggestelltes Rad" Fahrer="Schmidt" Operator="Pusch" Positionsbestimmungsverfahren="DGPS">
                <Messpunktabstand_Messgeschwindigkeit>1 Wert pro 1 Meter</Messpunktabstand_Messgeschwindigkeit>
                <Messpunktabstand_Fahrbahntemperatur>1 Wert pro 1 Meter</Messpunktabstand_Fahrbahntemperatur>
                <Messpunktabstand_Reifentemperatur>1 Wert pro 1 Meter</Messpunktabstand_Reifentemperatur>
                <Messpunktabstand_Lufttemperatur>1 Wert pro 1 Meter</Messpunktabstand_Lufttemperatur>
                <Messpunktabstand_Wassertemperatur>1 Wert pro 1 Meter</Messpunktabstand_Wassertemperatur>
                <Messpunktabstand_Seitenkraftbeiwert>1 Wert pro 1 Meter</Messpunktabstand_Seitenkraftbeiwert>
                <Messpunktabstand_Seitenabstand>1 Wert pro 1 Meter</Messpunktabstand_Seitenabstand>
                <Messlinie>rechte Rollspur</Messlinie>
            </Messparameter>
        </ZEBHeader>
        <Datenstrom LfdM="511" Datum="2012-05-31" Uhr="11:19:57" G="0" Bemerkung="" mrl="0" />
        <Datenstrom LfdM="525" Datum="2012-05-31" Uhr="11:19:58" G="0" Bemerkung="" mrl="0" />
    </ZEBMessstrecke>
</RohdatenTP2Netz>
```

Comment: You seem to have pasted the XML twice, rather than the code for `ZEBMessstrecke`...

Comment: One thing to try is to marshal a populated model to XML and then compare it to the XML you are trying to unmarshal.  Another thing to do is to generate an XML schema from your `JAXBContext` (see:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema) and then use it to validate your input document to make sure that it matches.

Comment: hmm yes   thats true    but i am not at work anymore so i change it at monday :D

Comment: sooo  i have edited this   now it shows the class

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan now i have the problem, it seems `JAXB` cant find the NS... i did ur tip, marshel a selfpopulated structure and unmarsheled it again. at the end he put an :ns2 in front of the root tag `<ns2:RohdatenTP2Netz>` and at the `ns-attribute`. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leverage the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace qualification for the classes in each of your packages.

**xml/package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://www.BASt.de/ZEB/Rohdaten/Version_3_0", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package xml;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**xml/messstrecke/package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "http://www.BASt.de/ZEB/Rohdaten/Version_3_0", 
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package xml.messstrecke;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead :

```
public @XmlElement(required = true, type = ZEBMessstrecke.class) List<ZEBMessstrecke> getZebMessstrecken()
```

You should use:

```
@XmlList 
@XmlElement(required = true, type = ZEBMessstrecke.class)
public List<ZEBMessstrecke> getZebMessstrecken()
```

Comment: thanks   but no it dont work.  ->  
xml.messstrecke.ZEBMessstrecke maps to a structured XML fragment (AKA complex type), and therefore incompatible with @XmlList.  

javadoc says, that XmlList puts simpletypes like Strings not into single childs, but into one separated with spaces

Answer (score 0):

Your `@XmlElement` annotation is on a method called `getZebMessstrecken`, so it will be looking for an element named `zebMessstrecken`, not `ZEBMessstrecke`.  You need to make the element name explicit, i.e.

```
@XmlElement(name = "ZEBMessstrecke", required = true)
```

Also, the usual way for JAXB to map a `maxOccurs="unbounded"` element is to generate only the getter, not the setter, and have the getter return an empty list the first time it is called.  The pattern is that the caller will get the `List` from the getter and then add elements to this list directly.  So try something like:

```
@XmlElement(name = "ZEBMessstrecke", required = true)
public List<ZEBMessstrecke> getZebMessstrecken() {
  if(zebMessstrecken == null) {
    zebMessstrecken = new ArrayList<ZEBMessstrecke>();
  }
  return zebMessstrecken;
}

// no setZebmessstrecken method
```

You don't need the `type` as it can be inferred from the method return type.

Edit: Also, check that you have the right namespace on the `@XmlType` annotation for the `ZEBMessstrecke` class.

Comment: this is my result of serveral hours of try and always error, this annotation was my begin. so no nothing changed. --> it stays null

Comment: thanks for th details but no, nothing changed... it didnt even call the getter methode. i changed the ZEBMessstrecke from colplex to simple Stringchild - only one no list - same thing, dont want to parse it.

Comment: Since your `ZEBMessstrecke` class is annotated `@XmlRootElement` rather than `@XmlType`, try using `@XmlElementRef` on the property instead of `@XmlElement`.

Comment: found the problem can u look at the question-comments thanks :D