# JAXB - unmarshalled fields are null

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

We are unmarshalling a response from http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/. This is the text sent to the marshall:

```
<NameSearch xmlns="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/NameSearch.xsd">
  <ContinuationKey>...</ContinuationKey>
  <RegressionKey>...</RegressionKey>
  <SearchRows>20</SearchRows>
  <CoSearchItem>
    <CompanyName>COMPANY NAME</CompanyName>
    <CompanyNumber>23546457</CompanyNumber>
    <DataSet>LIVE</DataSet>
    <CompanyIndexStatus>DISSOLVED</CompanyIndexStatus>
    <CompanyDate></CompanyDate>
  </CoSearchItem>
  // more CoSearchItem elements
</NameSearch>
```

The model of CoSearchItem is like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CoSearchItem", propOrder = {
    "companyName",
    "companyNumber",
    "dataSet",
    "companyIndexStatus",
    "companyDate",
    "searchMatch"
})
public class CoSearchItem {

    @XmlElement(name = "CompanyName", required = true)
    protected String companyName;
    @XmlElement(name = "CompanyNumber", required = true)
    protected String companyNumber;
    @XmlElement(name = "DataSet", required = true)
    protected String dataSet;
    @XmlElement(name = "CompanyIndexStatus")
    protected String companyIndexStatus;
    @XmlElement(name = "CompanyDate")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar companyDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "SearchMatch")
    protected String searchMatch;

    // getters and setters

}
```

NameSearch model has this structure:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "NameSearch", namespace = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema", propOrder = {
    "continuationKey",
    "regressionKey",
    "searchRows",
    "coSearchItem"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "NameSearch", namespace = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema")
public class NameSearch {

    @XmlElement(name = "ContinuationKey", required = true)
    protected String continuationKey;
    @XmlElement(name = "RegressionKey", required = true)
    protected String regressionKey;
    @XmlElement(name = "SearchRows", required = true)
    protected BigInteger searchRows;
    @XmlElement(name = "CoSearchItem")
    protected List<CoSearchItem> coSearchItem;

    // setters and getters

}
```

The package has this annotations:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, //
    xmlns = {
        @XmlNs(prefix = "xsi", namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") 
     }
)

package uk.gov.companieshouse;
```

The unmarshaling is done from the first `Node` extracted from a larger `Document`, inside an `any` list of items. When we parse the xml however all the fields in CoSearchItem are set to null and can't figure out the reason.

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747484/jaxb-parses-xml-child-into-null-only-the-attributes-are-set-in-the-object) help?

Comment: It points to the @XmlSchema like Blaise did, so sort of. I found out the issue after realizing the incorrect namespace qualification.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use a package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace qualification for your model.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

This this specified you do not require to specify the namespace URI on the `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlType` on your `NameSearch` class.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

---

> The unmarshaling is done from the first Node extracted from a larger
>   Document, inside an any list of items.

Make sure the DOM parer used to create the nodes is namespace aware.

```
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the package schema annotation :) It turns out it wasn't the correct one.

Comment: There was a change in java around 1.8.0_100 that make this answer the only correct way to set schema for all fields. Before that version @XmlRootElement was also working.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the correct answer thanks  to @[Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan). After looking at the package namespace qualification I found that it was pointing to:

```
"http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0"
```

and it should have been pointing to:

```
"http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema"
```

Not sure how that got misplaced.

Comment: That would do it. What was happening was that JAXB was thinking that each of the `@XmlElement` annotations was in the wrong namespace, so they weren't matching up when deserializing and so the data was getting dropped on the floor. (JAXB ignores unknown elements by default.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` in the xsd before generating stubs, else make the change manually in package-info.java