# Searching company name availability using Companies House XML gateway

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am not asking about the code here! I am asking about the flow here.

I want to search the company name availability via [XML gateway of Companies House](http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/). I know how to marshal and unmarshal the data using jabx in Java, but I don't know the exact flow of the application. Can anybody tell me where to start from? Companies House provide [sample XML request](http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/examples/namesearch_req.xml) and [sample XML response](http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/examples/namesearch_reply.xml).

Please find my code.

```
package Classes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.InputStreamRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;


public class PostXML {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Get target URL
        String strURL = "http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/xmlgw/Gateway" ;

        // Get file to be posted
        String strXMLFilename = "F:\\12-8\\CompanyFormation\\CompanyFormation\\web\\file.xml";
        File input = new File(strXMLFilename);

        // Prepare HTTP post
        PostMethod post = new PostMethod(strURL);

        // Request content will be retrieved directly
        // from the input stream
        // Per default, the request content needs to be buffered
        // in order to determine its length.
        // Request body buffering can be avoided when
        // content length is explicitly specified
        post.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(new FileInputStream(input), input.length()));

        // Specify content type and encoding
        // If content encoding is not explicitly specified
        // ISO-8859-1 is assumed
        post.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");

        // Get HTTP client
        HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

        // Execute request
        try {
            int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);

            // Display status code
            System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);

            // Display response
            System.out.println("Response body: ");
            System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            // Release current connection to the connection pool 
            // once you are done
            post.releaseConnection();
        }

    }
}
```

My generated request:

```xml
    <GovTalkMessage xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:gt="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <EnvelopeVersion>1.0</EnvelopeVersion>
  <Header>
    <MessageDetails>
      <Class>NameSearch</Class>
      <Qualifier>request</Qualifier>
      <TransactionID>1</TransactionID>
    </MessageDetails>
    <SenderDetails>
      <IDAuthentication>
        <SenderID>XMLGatewayTestUserID</SenderID>
        <Authentication>
          <Method>CHMD5</Method>
          <Value>XMLGatewayTestPassword</Value>
        </Authentication>
      </IDAuthentication>
    </SenderDetails>
  </Header>
  <GovTalkDetails>
    <Keys/>
  </GovTalkDetails>
  <Body>
<NameSearchRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/NameSearch.xsd">
<CompanyName>SPECIALIST PENSION SERVICES LIMITED</CompanyName>
<DataSet>LIVE</DataSet>
<SameAs>0</SameAs>
<SearchRows>100</SearchRows>
</NameSearchRequest>
  </Body>
</GovTalkMessage>
```

OUTPUT

Response status code: 200
Response body: 
Jan 07, 2014 12:30:02 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase getResponseBody
WARNING: Going to buffer response body of large or unknown size. Using getResponseBodyAsStream instead is recommended.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GovTalkMessage xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope http://xmlgw.companieshouse.gov.uk/v1-0/schema/Egov_ch-v2-0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/CM/envelope" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:gt="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/schemas/govtalk/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <EnvelopeVersion>1.0</EnvelopeVersion>
  <Header>
    <MessageDetails>
      <Class>NameSearch</Class>
      <Qualifier>error</Qualifier>
      <TransactionID>1</TransactionID>
      <GatewayTimestamp>2014-01-07T06:59:50-00:00</GatewayTimestamp>
    </MessageDetails>
    <SenderDetails>
      <IDAuthentication>
        <SenderID>XMLGatewayTestUserID</SenderID>
        <Authentication>
          <Method>CHMD5</Method>
          <Value>XMLGatewayTestPassword</Value>
        </Authentication>
      </IDAuthentication>
    </SenderDetails>
  </Header>
  <GovTalkDetails>
    <Keys/>
    <GovTalkErrors>
      <Error>
        <RaisedBy>NameSearch</RaisedBy>
        <Number>502</Number>
        <Type>fatal</Type>
        <Text>Authorisation Failure</Text>
        <Location></Location>
      </Error>
    </GovTalkErrors>
  </GovTalkDetails>
  <Body>
  </Body>
</GovTalkMessage>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085648/jaxb-unmarshalled-fields-are-null

Comment: What do you mean by "*the flow*"? Perhaps you can post the code you've already written and explain where you are stuck?

Comment: hello @Duncan i have posted my java code along with the passed xml and output xml, please suggest.

Comment: according to the documentation provided on the company houese website, 608 error code is for "Not a HTTPS Request".

Comment: So... did you try sending an HTTPS request?

Comment: yes when i tried with https:// instead http://, it doesnt give any output, its blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Class>` tag in `<MessageDetails>` is invalid. I believe the value you want is `NameSearch` (without the space).

Comment: Hello Tom! thanks, that solved my 608 error, but i get 502 authentication error now, though i have entered the right test credentials, please have a look at my edited question and code.